# Can Amazon Cloudfront Stream to an iOS Device

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am building a CDN. I want to be able to stream to an iPhone and iPad. Is this possible using Amazon Cloudfront?

Let me clarify. Is there any documentation anywhere or an example anywhere of someone doing this?

Comment: Yes. Many things are possible with Amazon Cloudfront.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. I want to know what protocols are used, or if there is documentation of someone doing this.

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way round. What protocols do you want to use? What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I am realizing now. I want to stream from Amazon Cloudfront to the iPad. Amazon Cloudfront supports RTMP streaming, but the iOS platform does not. How do I stream from the Amazon Cloudfront to an iOS device?

Comment: Is that the only option? If I understand correctly, HTTP is just downloading the video, with possible options of seeking to download later parts. What if the user has slow bandwidth?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3546/discussion-between-redeeze-and-michael-petrotta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progressive download works if you ensure that the media's metadata is at the beginning of the file.  Google "ffmpeg qtfastart" to accomplish this in the easiest manner (in my experience).  If this is not done, the player (in iOS) must download the complete file before it gets to the metadata that it needs to read in order to play.  If you are not doing this step in your production workflow, then your progressive download is not functioning as "progressive download", it is actually downloading the entire file (as stated before...so it can get to the metadata) and then playing.  This can be done with any video/audio file supported by your platform.

NOTE:  I am not sure how this affects any attempts at high-speed scrubbing.  It seems the file would need to be downloaded to the point that the app is trying to scrub to.

Another alternative may be to create the format needed for iOS streaming (using a segmenter/transcoder), and serving up those files through http on your regular Cloudfront distribution.  Theoretically that should work.

To be more clear - Cloudfront uses and older version of Flash Media Server(v 3.5) that supports streaming through various RTMP protocols.  These can be enabled by creating a Streaming Distribution (that is how we do streaming for web and Android) and using something like JW Player on the front end.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_TechOverview/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119ed944a1a-7ffa.html 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/ktowes_fms35.html

IOS streaming is done using HTTP Live Streaming which is different.  https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Your options would be to do as I mentioned above, or use EC2 and stand up your own FMS 4.5 instance ( http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/live-streaming-cloudfront-fms-4-5.html ).

Answer (score 1):

Have struggled a lot over this..

Finally got it working through Audio Streamer.. Love this ...

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html

Awesome way ....

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to use Progressive Download, which means upload the file to S3, create a distribution, and go! It's super simple.